# Problem playing higher swaras on Bansuri occationally on G Sharp

Tags: bansuri

I'm practicing with G sharp flute(Indian Bansuri) for notes (alankars) that include higher swaras. I have recently upgraded from A middle (23 inch) to G sharp (24 Inch) flute.

Occationally, I find it hard to produce proper higher notes Re Ga Ma on G Sharp. I noticed that at that immidiate moment, when I tried same swaras (Notes) on A middle flute it just produces the sound properly and I do not have problem blowing.

I thought G sharp would be a little easier to blow than A. Is this incorrect? Or could it be that my G sharp is a bit out of tune? But at other times I'm able to produce proper sound on it as well.

I'm Littlebit confused. Is it possible that my blowing is not in tune with G sharp yet and may be more practice will solve this itself? My confusion came from fact that when I face problem on G sharp, I can produce good sound on exact same moment on A bansuri.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bansuris are made by hand from natural materials so every instrument will play differently. There should be very little difference between an instrument in G-sharp and one in A, but the new instrument might not be as good as your old one, or it might simply respond differently. This will usually become more obvious as you play higher. Take some time to get to know the bansuri and you might find it plays just as easily as the other one.